# Replacing CGILua with other compatible framework>

Tags: model-view-controller, lua, cgilua

I have been using CGILua and lighttpd for my web server and applications. But, being classic it does not seem to provide safegaurds and security features expected of a modern framework. Like input validation, and other I had to implement from UI application. 
I want to replace this with other compatible frameworks out there. I have surfed about orbit, lapis, sailor. These are some latest frameworks.

can I know, out of all which would provide backward compatibility for my server? I mean with less porting efforts, which would provide handy compatibility. Even if there are others out there, do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It probably no any frameworks, that would be fully compatible and wouldn't require porting, but answering your second question, you can take a look on [Webmcp](http://www.public-software-group.org/webmcp) framework, for example.

Although, I myself would prefer to use NginX+ngx_mod_lua+resty-template ;)